# Posting form data to Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: php, forms, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, encode

I've spent three days now trying to set up a simple posting form to amazon s3.
Everytime I get this error:

> SignatureDoesNotMatchThe request signature we calculated does not
>   match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.

I don't see the problem. :-(

```
<?php
        $form = array(
            'key'                       => 'queue/1_1_1234567890.wmv',
            'AWSAccessKeyId'            => 'mypublickeyishere',
            'acl'                       => 'public-read',
            'success_action_redirect'   => 'http://someurl.com',
        );

        $form['policy'] = '{
            "expiration": "2015-12-01T12:00:00.000Z",
                "conditions": [
                    {
                        "acl": "'.$form['acl'].'"
                    },
                    {
                        "success_action_redirect": "'.$form['success_action_redirect'].'"
                    },
                    {
                        "bucket": "thenameofmybucket"
                    },
                    [
                        "starts-with",
                        "$key",
                        "queue/"
                    ]
                ]
            }';

    $form['policy_encoded'] = base64_encode($form['policy']);
    $form['signature'] = base64_encode(hash_hmac( 'sha1', base64_encode(utf8_encode($form['policy'])), 'F90mc5kpjuNMPg8XG7iV6bxOzacYhktcw+RVGzpZ'));

?>


<form action="https://thenameofmybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="hidden" name="key" value="<?php echo $form['key'] ?>">
      <input type="hidden" name="AWSAccessKeyId" value="<?php echo $form['AWSAccessKeyId'] ?>">
      <input type="hidden" name="acl" value="<?php echo $form['acl'] ?>">
      <input type="hidden" name="success_action_redirect" value="<?php echo $form['success_action_redirect'] ?>">
      <input type="hidden" name="policy" value="<?php echo $form['policy_encoded'] ?>">
      <input type="hidden" name="signature" value="<?php echo $form['signature'] ?>">

      File to upload to S3:
      <input name="file" type="file">
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Upload File to S3">
</form>
```

I substituted the bucket name as well as the private and public keys above.

I followed the instruction to sign the policy meticulously:
http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/2006-03-01/dev/HTTPPOSTForms.html#HTTPPOSTConstructPolicy

What am I missing? Why is the code not working?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay, I finally managed to get this done using this sample code library:
http://aws.amazon.com/code/Amazon-S3/1618

Comment: Btw, the browser/operating system was crashing, because I was sending form fields that were not in the policy. After adding the x-ignore- to the fields, it worked. No idea why that caused a crash.

Comment: You should accept the answer that actually contains the solution to the issue encountered.

Answer (score 16):

There is no need for that library, you were just missing a parameter. The problem is that you have not set the hash_hmac function to output binary data. To do this, set the fourth parameter to `true` like so:

```
$signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $policy_b64, $secret, true));
```

If you do not set this, it will not be encoding the signature the way that AWS expects it to be.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem and this was exactly what I needed. Thanks. (This should be the accepted answer.)

Comment: Ditto. And yes, this should be the accepted answer, as it clearly resolved the original question. Oh well! Have an upvote anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Already answered your own question I realize, but I wonder if this tutorial (http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1434), which suggests you have to strip out the return characters from the json before doing the base 64 encoding is the root of the problem?